# Just installed the latest ubuntu version and my earphones don't work

Tags: sound

My earphones are fine but not working on ubuntu. My speakers work just fine with ubuntu. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install Pulse Audio by opening a Terminal windows ant type:

> sudo apt-get install pavucontrol

Open Pulse and check or set audio output to headphones. And check the volume for headphones. Unmute if necessary.